# Ajax callback in chain

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, chaining

I'm having a navigation bar on my site, and it's being built in some chain:

```
// in Init method
nav
    .hideContainer()
    .fetchData()
    .buildHTML()
    .eventify()
    .showContainer();
```

It's OK, and works fine for me. But in `fetchData` method I use local data to load ( inline json). But now, I need to get remote data (from an ajax calling). Can I make it without changing `Init` method?

I had an attempt to do this with an synchronous ajax call:

```
// in fetchData() method
var data;
$.ajax ({
     async: false,
     url : '/some/url/',
     success : function(res) {
         data = res;
     }
});
return data;
```

But I know, that it's slow - it's blocking the browser while it's loading.

I know, that I can modify my `Init` method, like in a such way:

```
nav
    .hideContainer()
    .fetchData(function(){
        nav.buildHTML().eventify().showContainer()

 });
```

But, I'd like not to modify `Init` method, can I do this?

P.S. I think I should go in direction of `Deffered` object. Am I right?

Comment: No, you cannot leave init intact *and* have ajax running asynchronously. The point of it being asynchronous is that it will return immediately so Init cannot work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `$.ajax` working asynchronously and at the same time expect `.fetchData()` to return with your data.

You are right that setting `async: false` is bad and changing the `init()` is a better alternative even when you lose elegant chaining.

You can change your code like this:

```
function fetchData() {
  // ...
  return $.ajax ({
    url : '/some/url/',
    success : function(res) {
     data = res;
    }
  });
}

function init() {
  // ...
  nav
    .hideContainer()
    .fetchData()
    .done(function() {
      nav
        .buildHTML()
        .eventify()
        .showContainer(); });
```

You don't have to introduce callbacks into `fetchData()` function, because you can return [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) returned by `ajax()` and then call `done()` on it - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

See also [fail()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) and [then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) if you want to handle errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in your fetch Method

```
$.ajax ({
     url : '/some/url/',
     success : buildHTML
});
```

Then, when the data comes in, it will call buildHTML()